# Array IF formula to transpose calendar days returns #N/A on last day of the month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created the following formula to create a calendar based on the users month entry selection.

```
{=IF(COLUMN($M$5:$AT$5)-COLUMN($M$5)+1>SUMPRODUCT(0+(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT($L$6&":"&EOMONTH($L$6,0))),1)<8)),"",TRANSPOSE(SMALL(IF(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT($L$6&":"&EOMONTH($L$6,0))),1)<8,ROW(INDIRECT($L$6&":"&EOMONTH($L$6,0)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&EOMONTH($L$6,0)-$L$6)))))}
```

The formula works great, however, the last day of the month returns #N/A. No matter what month the user enters, the last day returns the error.  Here is a sample using December (I hid columns to save the space):

[image]

As you can see, every day works except the last one.  I thought it was because there were 31 days, so I used a month with 30 days:

[image]

Same result. There is got to be something wrong with the formula, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: can you explain in words what you're trying to do?  Seems awfully complicated when you can just put in a date in M6 and in N6 put in =M6+1 and drag across.

Comment: @sous2817 I trying to create a dymanic calendar. If the users enters the month on L6, then M:AQ will fill in the month for the user. This is part of a bigger spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't promise to dissect your formula in its entirety, though I will tell you the reason for your error (by the way, I would've thought this would produce a #REF! error, not #N/A - can you clarify?)

If the date in L6 is the end of the month, then this part (at the end of your formula):

=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&EOMONTH($L$6,0)-$L$6))

will resolve to (since the end of the month pertaining to the entry in L6 is, in this case, precisely the same as the value in L6):

=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&0))

which is:

=ROW(INDIRECT("1:0"))

and, since 1:0 is not a valid range reference, this part errors (though errors with #REF!, which is why I asked you about this).

Regards

Comment: The date in L6 is the beginning of the month. You are right I should be getting a #REF but I am getting a #N/A (see the screenshot above).

Comment: So is the formula you posted that which pertains to column AQ, in which the error is shown, or that which pertains to column M? If the latter, I'm afraid it's not very useful in terms of offering you an explanation.

Comment: I figure out the problem.  It was on the EOMonth. I was using EOMONTH($L$6,0) instead of EOMONTH($L$6,1) which displays the last day of the month, one month after the date in the cell being referenced L6

Comment: But that's precisely what my dissection gave. Oh well, congratulations in any case on figuring it out!